# Возможно ли в LaTeX сделать обтекание рисунка списком?

Tags: latex

При попытке изменить обтекания текста на список картинка уходит вниз. На картинке показано, как это выглядит в Google Books, возможно ли реализовать что-то похожее 
в LaTeX?

[image: Хотелось бы нечто похожее]

Answer (score 3):

Как указано в [документации](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) к пакету `wrapfig`, окружение для "обтекания"  `wrapfigure` не будет корректно работать ни внутри любых списков, ни рядом с ними. Но то, что Вы указали, на самом деле не требует обтекания текстом. В Вашем примере рисунок находится **рядом** со списком. А этого можно достичь разными способами. Самое простое - расположить и рисунок и список внутри окружений `minipage` и расположить их рядом. Например, так:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[2]

\vskip5mm
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{birds}
    \end{center}
    \captionof{figure}{Birds}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \blinditemize[7]
\end{minipage}
\vskip5mm

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

В результате получится что-то типа:

---

[image: Пример расположения рисунка и списка рядом]

---

И еще несколько замечаний по примеру. *Первое*: параметр `demo` у пакета `graphicx` вместо рисунка рисует черный прямоугольник, при этом позволяя компилировать документ без самого рисунка. Естественно, этот параметр нужно будет удалить для работы с реальным рисунком. *Второе*: пример списка и текста у меня задается командами `\blinditemize` и `\blindtext` из пакета `blindtext`. В реальном документе этот пакет не нужен.